# custom coloring with if else in swiftui?

Tags: swift, api, swiftui

I am making an earthquake application on SwiftUI. The data I receive includes the magnitude of the earthquake and I want the text I print on the screen to change color according to this magnitude.

For example, I can say: I want it to show green if it is less than 3, yellow if it is between 3 and 5, red if it is between 5 and 7, black if it is greater than 7.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ternary` operators to show green if it is less than 3, yellow if it is between 3 and 5, red if it is between 5 and 7, black if it is greater than 7. For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quake = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("quake in ")
            .foregroundColor(quake < 3 ? .green
                             : quake <= 5 ? .yellow
                             : quake <= 7 ? .red
                             : .black)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this problem, I believe if you know how to do an if-else statement, you can do it yourself. Since you're struggling with probably swift or swiftUI itself

here are 3 ways ways you can do it
first is

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quake = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        if (quake < 3) {
           Text("Earthquake")
             .foregroundColor(.green)
        } else if (quake <= 5) {
           Text("Earthquake")
             .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        } else if // etc...
    }
}
```

but it's very inefficient, therefore the 2nd solution is to iterate it within the foreground color itself

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quake = 2
    
    var body: some View {
      Text("Earthquake")
             .foregroundColor(quake < 3 ? .green : quake <= 5 ? .yellow : // etc)
    }
}
```

all you have to do is put the

```
condiditon ? if its true : if codition ?  if it's true : if condition //etc untill else
```

it's basicaly like

```
if condition then do something
else if condition
 up untill
else
```

the last solution is to create a function that returns the key, i believe this one is far more beginner-friendly compared to the 2nd one

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quake = 2

    private func getColor() -> Color {
        if quake <= 3 {
            return .green
        } else if quake <= 5 {
            return .yellow
        }
        return .black // default, random, you decide the last condition
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text("Earthquake")
            .foregroundColor(self.getColor())
    }
}
```